# Distance in Poincaré disc

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry

I'm trying to prove that two points $x$ and $y$ in the Poincaré disc $\mathbb D \subset \mathbb R^2$ of radius $1$ is given by 
$$
d_H(x,y) = \cosh^{-1}\left(1+\frac{2|x-y|^2}{(1-|x|^2)(1-|y|)^2}\right) 
$$
where $|x| = \sqrt{(x^1)^2 + (x^2)^2}$ is the Euclidean length of $x \in \mathbb R^2$. The Riemannian metric on $\mathbb D$ is given by
$$
g = 4\frac{(dx^1)^2 + (dx^2)^2}{(1-|x|^2)^2}
$$
It suffices to consider the case where $x = 0$ and $y = (a,0)$ for some $a > 0$, by frame homogeneity of $\mathbb D$. Geodesic curves through the origin are diameter line segments of the disc, so we let $\gamma(t) = (t,0)$; when parametrized with $0 \leq t \leq a$, the resulting curve is length-minimizing. The speed of this curve in the above metric is 
$$
\left|\dot\gamma(t)\right| = \sqrt{g_{(t,0)}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^1}, \frac{\partial}{\partial x^1}\right)} =  \sqrt{\frac{4}{\left(1-t^2\right)^2}} = \frac{2}{1-t^2}
$$
whence the length of the curve $\gamma$ -- that is, the distance from the origin to the point $y=(a,0)$ -- is:
$$
L_g(\gamma) = d_H(x,y) = \int_0^a \frac{2}{1-t^2}\,dt = 2\tanh^{-1}(a)
$$
However, I'd like to show that this is equal to $\cosh^{-1}\left(1+\frac{2a^2}{1-a^2}\right)$, which is what we're trying to prove. Is there an identity here that I'm missing, or did I make a mistake in my calculations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to write $cosh$ in function of $tanh$

Let be $tanh(x)=y$.

$cosh(2x)=cosh^2(x)+sinh^2(x)=$

$=\frac{cosh^2(x)+sinh^2(x)}{cosh(x)^2-sinh(x)^2}=$

$=\frac{1+y^2}{1-y^2}$

Then in your case if you choose

$x=tanh^{-1}(a)$ you have that

$cosh(2x)=\frac{1+tanh^2(x)}{1-(tanh(x))^2}=\frac{1+a^2}{1-a^2}=1+\frac{2a^2}{1-a^2}$

So

$2x=cosh^{-1}(1+\frac{2a^2}{1-a^2})$ that means

$2tanh^{-1}(a)=cosh^{-1}(1+\frac{2a^2}{1-a^2})$

So

$L_g(\gamma)= cosh^{-1}(1+\frac{2a^2}{1-a^2})$

Comment: I'm not sure this calculation is correct. Your first assertion, $\cosh(2x) = 1+\sinh(2x)$, is not true. I agree with the rest of the calculation, and that one would like to show $$\cosh(2x) = 1 + 2\frac{\tanh(x)}{1-\tanh^2(x)} = 1 + 2\cosh(x)\sinh(x)$$ but this generally isn't true since $\cosh(2x) - \sinh(2x) \neq 1$.

Comment: @DFord thanks you, I corrected my answer.